# Can we retain the session once the session is timed out?

Tags: session-timeout, xforms

Say for instance, my session is timed out. After this, is it possible for me to provide a dialog box to the user asking if the user wants to continue the session or not ? The dialog will have 2 buttons OK and Cancel. If the user clicks OK, is it possible to retain the same session ? Can this be implemented in xforms ? Also, how can I display this dialog box when the session is timed out ?

```
ORBEON.xforms.Events.errorEvent.subscribe(function(eventName, eventData) {

});
```

The above Java script code will be executed if any error occurs in the form. But I want something to be executed only on session time-out. How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

Once the session has timed out, you can't do anything in XForms anymore, as the XForms state for the page has been lost. When your listener to the `errorEvent` is called, you can do anything you want in JavaScript, but if the error was caused by the session being expired, again, you can't run XForms code to display a dialog. Also, the [session heartbeat](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-state-handling#TOC-Session-heartbeat) feature, which is enabled by default, should minimize the occurrences of session expiring while users still having a page loaded.

In most cases, people use this error handler to inform users that the session has expired and then redirect them to the login page.